# Accessing rows using Mysqldatareader

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there a way to access and assign the High Column's (i+1)th or the (I-1)th value?

My Code is as follows:

```
public static List<db1> Read_DB1(string date, MySqlConnection conn)
{
string sql = "select * from table2replica where Date=\'" + date + "\'"; // loads for a particular date


            List<db1> db1List = new List<db1>();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            db1 db1Obj = new db1();
                            db1Obj.Symbol = reader["Stock"].ToString();
                            db1Obj.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]);
                            db1Obj.Open = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Open"]);
                            db1Obj.High = Convert.ToDouble(reader["High"]);
                            db1Obj.Low = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Low"]);
                            db1List.Add(db1Obj);

                      }
                }
            }
```

Should I reference and assign the value of the next row using :

```
db1Obj.HighNextRow = Convert.ToDouble(reader["High"]+1)
```

or

```
db1Obj.PreviousRow = Convert.ToDouble(reader["High"+1])
```

Comment: Please explain what is your problem. A DbDataReader is a forward only kind of cursor. You cannot go back and forward at your will.

Comment: Oh, I thought I could assign for example the 10th row of High Column to a variable called say db1Obj.HighNextRow by adding an constant index

Answer (score 1):

A DbDataReader can move only forward and in any given loop it has knowledge only of the current *record*. You cannot jump back to read a field of the previous record or forward to read a field of the next record.

However, you can track this previous record yourself keeping the previous instance of db1Obj alive.

```
db1 db1Obj = null;
db1 prevObj = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    db1Obj = new db1();
    db1Obj.Symbol = reader["Stock"].ToString();
    db1Obj.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]);
    db1Obj.Open = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Open"]);
    db1Obj.High = Convert.ToDouble(reader["High"]);
    db1Obj.Low = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Low"]);
    if(prevObj != null) 
    {
        prevObj.HighNextRow = db1Obj.High;
        db1Obj.PrevRow = prevObj.High;
    }
    prevObj = db1Obj;
    db1List.Add(db1Obj);
}
if(prevObj != null && db1Obj != null) 
{
   prevObj.HighNextRow = db1Obj.High;
   db1Obj.PrevRow = prevObj.High;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Steve, but is there a way to access the next row using a for loop ?

Comment: Not with a DataReader. After putting everything in the list you can access any element using an index.